# Dapper column to F# option property

Tags: f#, dapper, option-type

How do I get Dapper to convert data to an F# type with an `option` property? Simple example:

```
type SomeType = {
    Count : int option
}

connection.QueryAsync<SomeType>(...)
```

This throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
    A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature
    (System.Int32 count) is required for SomeType materialization
```

Using `Nullable` instead of option works:

```
type SomeType = {
    Count : Nullable<int>
}
```

But it's not as desirable for various reasons. For one thing, I have cases where I use `string option` (because F# doesn't allow null assignments normally, which is great), and `Nullable<string>` doesn't compile. Is there a way to configure/instruct Dapper to automatically deal with `option` types? I'd like to avoid using custom mappings every time.

In case it matters, using with Npgsql.

Comment: I think you'll want to look at [Type Handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dapper/6/type-handlers#t=201703142216128943082).

Comment: Hmm, the examples don't seem to cover a generic type like `Option<'T>`.

Comment: do you need to use Dapper? [`SqlProvider`](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/postgresql.html) can deal with option types.

Comment: It's also possible that Dapper wants mutable types, so maybe better to mark the types with [<CLIMutable>] attribute, or use a class, with `member val` and define default values.

Comment: @s952163 immutable types are not a problem. It works fine aside from option types. Dapper just maps rows to types, which is exactly what I need. SqlProvider is not the right tool for that job.

Comment: Ah, in that case hopefully someone with more Dapper experience will chime in. Re:  Sqlprovider, it does something similar with [.MapTo](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider//core/mappers.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there's any support for adding handlers for open generics, so you'd have to add a type handler for each type you need.

You could define a handler like this:

```
type OptionHandler<'T>() =
    inherit SqlMapper.TypeHandler<option<'T>>()

    override __.SetValue(param, value) = 
        let valueOrNull = 
            match value with
            | Some x -> box x
            | None -> null

        param.Value <- valueOrNull    

    override __.Parse value =
        if isNull value || value = box DBNull.Value 
        then None
        else Some (value :?> 'T)
```

And register for the types you need like this:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler (OptionHandler<string>())
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler (OptionHandler<int>())
```